# Too many positional arugments using constructor

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My First Post - Please Help me to Solve my Issue

Guys This is My Code of Cart Screen I Have to Call My Main Screen With Selected Index = 2 from Cart Screen
but I am Having Issues with this.
Can Somebody Help me to Solve My Issue
My Main Screen Code is here -

```dart
const MainScreen(selectedMainIndex == 2);
```

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget { 
final int? id; 
const MainScreen({Key? key, this.id}) : super(key: key);
```

I Have to Call
MainScreen With selectedMainIndex = 2
from Another Screen

I Have Imported Main Screen But I Cant Find Where is My Mistake??

Using Flutter 3.3

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead of text, more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: bro i cannot edit this question actually i have to call a screen into my another screen but i have to call it with selectedMainIndex = 2 how can i call it with selectedMainIndex

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass value on a named constructor,

```dart
final int? id; 
const MainScreen({Key? key, this.id}) : super(key: key);
```

you need to do

```dart
MainScreen(selectedMainIndex: 2)
```

Instead of `==`, it will be `:`.

Find more about [#using-constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)